# Every time I open Visual Studio 2017 (Community) I have to set everything up again

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Every single time I open VS I have to go through the settings (log in, dark/light theme, etc.) This is really annoying as it takes quite a while.
[image]

Is there a way to fix this? Or do I have to live with setting everything up again?

Comment: Help -> Send Feedback -> Report a Problem.

Comment: Check you permissions on the folder that it stores your configuration in.